# Css class vs html tag in css

Tags: css

In a html page i have this code

```
<style>
 table, th, td {
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
}

.table-noborder {
 border-collapse: collapse; 
 border: none;
 width: 100%; border-style: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Is there a way to specify when we use table-noborder in table tag to not apply what is specified for table, th, td?

Comment: You would need to override the global style with the class.

Comment: No. All rules of all selectors that apply to an element are cumulative. If you want `.table-noborder` tables to not have something you set in `table`, you need to explicitly _unset_ that rule in `.table-noborder` (set the value of the rule to its normal default).

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `.table-noborder *`?

Comment: You don't have to explicitly type the reverted / initial CSS definition again. Use `initial`, `inherit`, `unset`, `revert`, etc.. See [MDN: CSS - initial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pseudo-selector `:not()` and still keep a single rule

```css
table:not(.table-noborder),
table:not(.table-noborder) th,
table:not(.table-noborder) td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr />
<table class="table-noborder">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```